# How can I use setf on a dynamic variable effectively through a function call?

Tags: scope, lisp, common-lisp

I am using dynamic variables, let's call one of them `*x*` with a value of 10.

I want to change its value through a function call by passing the variable's name as the parameter:

```
(defun change-value (varname)
  (setf varname 20))
```

then calling `(change-value *x*)`. If I understand correctly, `varname` takes local scope and therefore the `setf` has no effect outside `change-value`. So, `*x*` remains as 10 afterwards.

My question is, is there a way to make `*x*` equal to 20 through a function call similar to the above? I tried adding `(proclaim '(special varname))` and `(declare (special varname))` and they don't seem to do anything.

Oh, and defining a macro does more or less what I want, but I doubt this is good practice:

```
(defmacro change-value-macro (varname)
  `(setf ,varname 20))

(change-value-macro *x*)
```

Comment: `(defun change-value-of-x (value) (setf *x* value))`? Or just `(setf *x* value)` directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Defining

```
(defparameter *x* 10)
(defun change-value (varname) ; the argument name is misleading!
  (setf varname 20))
```

and calling `(change-value *x*)` does not buy you anything because `change-value` is a function and you just passed it `10` as the argument; it has no idea that `*x*` is involved. So, what the function does is modify the local binding of the variable `varname`, changing it from `10` to `20` and returning the latter.

You need to pass the `symbol` (variable name) itself:

```
(defun change-value (varname)
  (setf (symbol-value varname) 20))
```

and call it as `(change-value '*x*)` (note the quote mark `'` before `*x*`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now wouldn't the consequence of passing 10 as the argument result in (setf 10 20)? Shouldn't we then get an error?

Comment: @HeitorChang: you would get the error if you pass unquoted `*x*` to my version. Note that `setf` does *not* evaluate the `varname` in your version, so you are not setting 10 to 20, you are setting `varname` to 20.

Comment: @sds OK, I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
(defparameter *x* 'initial)

(defun change-dyn (variable value)
  (setf (symbol-value variable) value))

(change-dyn '*x* 'final)
```